# React JS (JSX) div not rendering unless text is added to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to render an image inside a div tag using styling as I want the image to dynamically resize based upon the size of the window.

Here is the JSX code

```
const heroImage = "pathToImage";

const heroImageStyling = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${heroImage})`
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div style={heroImageStyling}></div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Running this doesn't render anything on the page

If text is added to the div tag like so, a small portion of the image is rendered to the screen (a long strip the same height as the text)

```
<div style={heroImageStyling}>Test Text</div>
```

How could I correct this problem and render the image to the screen?

Comment: Usually in HTML, we just add a width and height param, like: <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">. Make sure the w/h matches up with the image so the entire image will be drawn. Without the w/h params, your browser assumes the div is empty and will not draw it.

Comment: To note, this is inline styling and can make edits to HTML very difficult. I would recommend creating a class in CSS with the width (and/or height) set (like "width: 100px; height: 100px;") and including it in your div like <div class="classxxx">. I forgot this after my time ran out for my last question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

div without content and width height won't render. You can have 2 approaches here:

1. put `&nbsp;` inside div (when you don't want to define width/height)

`ReactDOM.render(
  <div style={heroImageStyling}>&nbsp;</div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);`

2. define either width or height or both in div styling

`const heroImageStyling = {
  backgroundImage:`url(${heroImage})`,
  height: 200px,
  width: 200px
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <div style={heroImageStyling}></div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);`

Comment: Adding &nbsp; inside the div renders only small strip of the image. The only option I see would be to use jquery to get the size of the window in terms of height and then manually assign the height

Comment: Sizing of image should be part of styling image itself and not the div

Comment: The image needs to change size based on the size of the window therefore I cannot specify a size in styling

Comment: Then you can define height and width of in %, therefore depending upon window size

Comment: Unfortunately using %'s didn't seem to work in my case. Fixed the issue with some simple jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try set height style to div like this

```
const heroImageStyling = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${heroImage})`,
  height: 300px,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by manually adding a height property to the div tag using Jquery to get the window height

```
let screenHeight = $(window).height() + "px";

const heroImageStyling = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${heroImage})`,
  height: screenHeight
};
```

Comment: Could you use `100vh` to maintain separated styles and JS?

Comment: Using 100vh as the height property also seemed to render nothing. Only method that has worked so far is setting the height of the image to pixels.